# Persistent network namespace configuration

Tags: linux, networking, namespace

When creating a namespace with `ip netns add <namespace>` the namespace and its related config are deleted on reboot along with created interfaces like veth pairs. What is the correct way to:

1. Create network namespaces on boot (or create persistent namespace configuration if that's a more correct way to put it?)
2. Create veth pairs on boot, set them to the appropriate namespace, bring them up and configure IP address?
3. Bring a physical interface up without assigning it an IP address so I can add it to an Open vSwitch (I have added `iface <name> inet manual` to `/etc/network/interface`, is this the right way?)

Any help would be appreciated along with references to proper documentation or explanations.

Comment: Which distro are you running?

Comment: Ubuntu server 16.04

Comment: I do not know specifically about  Ubuntu but all distributions allow you normally to attach hooks to interfaces/network being put up or down, so you should use that to run a script of yours that would setup the namespace on the other things you need.

Comment: See [How to create permanent linux network namespace](https://serverfault.com/questions/795419/how-to-create-permanent-linux-network-namespace) on ServerFault.